# xcode 4.4 neon assembly error

Tags: neon, xcode4.4

I get compilation errors when compiling neon assembly in `Xcode 4.4`, those error wasn't in xCode 4.3,
the errors are for those commands type:

```
error: invalid operand for instruction
        vld1 q5.u8, [r12], r2 

error: invalid operand for instruction
  vrhadd d0.u8,d22.u8,d0.u8

error: unexpected token in argument list
        vst1 d2.u32[0], [r1], r3
```

any idea how to solve those errors?
Thank you,

Comment: Try to change your compiler from llvm to gcc

Answer (score 1):

replace `vld1 q5.u8, [r12], r2` by `vld1.u8 q5, [r12], r2`

replace `vrhadd d0.u8,d22.u8,d0.u8` by `vrhadd.u8 d0,d22,d0`

replace `vst1 d2.u32[0], [r1], r3` by `vst1.u32 d2[0], [r1], r3`

This is the instruction that should by type by the size of the regsiter! not the register themselves

Comment: +1, though the proper syntax is actually `vld1.8`, not `vld1.u8` (both might well be accepted, but the first is formally correct).  Ditto for `vst1.32`.